# Using a third party library which depends on NLog from a .NET 6 application

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

As per the title, I have a third party library supplied in the form of DLLs, these DLLs have a dependency on NLog.dll (4.3.5) which is also supplied. When I try and start the library from a .NET 6 client I get the following exception. "Method not found: System.String System.AppDomainSetup.get_ConfigurationFile()". Apparently NLog is looking for a config file which in the past would have been in the App.config file. Searching the internet it appears one can supply the config file via a call to the NLog API, but I can't do this as I have no access to the underlying API. Does anybody know of a way of getting this setup working?

Comment: Why you're using NLog.dll (4.3.5)? There are newer versions that support .NET 5

Comment: I don't have any control over the version supplied. I presume I can't just substitute a newer one?

Comment: @Craig You should ask your supplier to provide a nuget-package for their library, that supports the target-platform NetStandard2.0 (It will ensure that it works for Net6).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs in `NLog.Internal.Fakeables.AppDomainWrapper` which is initialized like this:

```
public static AppDomainWrapper CurrentDomain => new AppDomainWrapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain);
```

Then later in AppDomainWrapper ctor:

```
public AppDomainWrapper(AppDomain appDomain)
{
    BaseDirectory = appDomain.BaseDirectory;
    // SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile doesn't exist in .NET 6
    ConfigurationFile = appDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile;
```

Many Constructors of NLog are using this `AppDomainWrapper.CurrentDomain` which will Error every time you use a NLog class.

Here is a nice StackTrace:

```
at NLog.Internal.Fakeables.AppDomainWrapper..ctor(AppDomain appDomain) in NLog\Internal\Fakeables\AppDomainWrapper.cs:line 58
at NLog.Internal.Fakeables.AppDomainWrapper.get_CurrentDomain()
at NLog.LogFactory.get_CurrentAppDomain() in NLog\LogFactory.cs:line 154
at NLog.LogFactory..ctor() in NLog\LogFactory.cs:line 316
at NLog.LogManager..cctor() in NLog\LogManager.cs:line 133
```

So i don't have much hope for you using this old version.

Comment: Thanks - I'm going to have to go to the supplier - they should be using a newer version of NLog in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Although you are correct about App.config there are other options, for example I have a .net 6 application that uses Nlog. The config file I use is called NLog.config (and NLog.dev.config). Full details are on the NLog Configuraiton file documentation https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. Is my version on NLog too old to support this config?

Comment: That may well be the issue, I'm using 4.7.13, I guess the alternative is to go back to an earlier version of .net